# Which property is being used to find side of cube, inscribed in a sphere.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

It is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg7YV.jpg)

[image]

that for finding the side length of a cube, need take an edge of length $3d.$
Then need draw a semicircle of radius $1.5d.$
Then, touch the semicircle with perpendicular thrown from a distance $=d,$ from an end.
This perpendicular is shown to touch the semicircle at $P.$
Unable to understand why the length of segment $QP$ is unspecified.
Neither any hint is given.
Earlier thought that the golden ratio is used, but seems some geometrical principle wrt the semicircle is at work.

Due to lack of information about the length of the edge $QP,$ am unable to find the length of segment $PS.$

Comment: I have included the first page into your question (not the second which contents no important information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $O$ the common center of the cube and sphere.

Let $R$ be the radius of the sphere and $2L$ be the sidelength of the cube.

Call $A,B,C$ the centers of 3 mutually adjacent faces of the cube meeting in a point $D$ belonging to the sphere

We have $$\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}=\vec{OD}\tag{1}$$

The LHS of (1) is, with respect to coordinate basis $\vec{OA},\vec{OB},\vec{OC}$:

$$\pmatrix{L\\0\\0}+\pmatrix{0\\L\\0}+\pmatrix{0\\0\\L}=\pmatrix{L\\L\\L}$$

with length $\sqrt{L^2+L^2+L^2}$ while the norm of the RHS of (1) is $R$. Therefore :

$$\sqrt{3L^2}=R \ \iff \ L=\frac{R}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Therefore, the sidelength of the cube is

$$2L=\frac{2R}{\sqrt{3}}\tag{2}$$

---

**Edit :** About your initial question :

According to the text, we have to prove that if length $AG$ = length $NS \ = \ 2R$ (where $R$ is the radius of the sphere), then length $SP$ is equal to the sidelength of the cube (given by formula (2) above).

Proof :As $Q$ divides $NS$ into the ratio $2:1$, we have $QN=\frac43R$ and $QS=\frac23R$. Using classical formula :

$$QP^2 = QN.QS$$

(the main altitude of a right triangle is the geometric mean of the segments in which it divides the hypotenuse), we deduce that :

$$QP^2 = \frac89R^2.$$

Applying now Pythagoras to right triangle $PQS$, we have :

$$SP^2=SQ^2+QP^2=\frac49R^2+\frac89R^2=\frac{4}{3}R^2$$

which is equivalent to (2).

Comment: That means that the length $PS=2d/\sqrt{3},$ (where you have that as $= R/\sqrt{3}.$) But the way in which the value of the needed edge $PS$ is found, doesn't make it clear the length of edge $PQ.$ Also, $PS^2 = PQ^2 + QS^2\implies 4d^2/3= PQ^2 + QS^2.$ But, what is $PQ,$ though it doesn't help to know that $QS=d.$

Comment: It is true that I haven't made a comment on the initial text because it appeared to me to be very confusing (it is not rare when looking at the original works of Euclid). I will come back to it.